# GetModuleBaseAddress() function not working properly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, 64-bit

I wanted to make a really simple hack for "Enter The Gungeon" game. I tried getting BaseModuleAddress for it, so further on I can get some pointers and work with them. But my GetModuleBaseAddress() function not working properly as I wanted it to work.
Note: The app is 64 bit.

A lot of times I've tried reworking the function, I didn't succeed though.

```cpp
DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress(TCHAR* lpszModuleName, DWORD pID) { // Getting module base address
        DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pID);
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = { 0 };
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
        {
            do {
                if (_tcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));


        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
        return dwModuleBaseAddress;
    }

    int main() {    
        char moduleName[] = "mono.dll";
        HWND procHwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Enter the Gungeon"); // Process stuff
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(procHwnd, &pid);
        HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, pid);
        DWORD moduleAddress = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(moduleName), pid);
        DWORD b_moduleAddress;
        ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, LPCVOID(moduleAddress), &b_moduleAddress, sizeof(b_moduleAddress), NULL); // Reading from module base address
        std::cout << "Process id - " << pid << "\n" << " \n"; // Printing them all
        std::cout << "ModuleBaseAddress - " << moduleAddress << "\n" << " \n";
        std::cout << "ModuleBaseAddress Address - " << b_moduleAddress << "\n" << " \n";

        std::cin.get();
    }
```

I expect GetModuleBaseAddress working and giving me the correct base module address.

Comment: What does it do instead? Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: @MadPhysicist http://prntscr.com/p03ffz And no, I didn't try running it through a debugger.

Comment: You should add that to the question, as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using DWORD to represent an address which is only 4 bytes, on x64 apps addresses need to be 8 bytes.

Your issue can be solved by using uintptr_t or other define/typedef which resolves to the correct pointer size based on the architecture you're building for.

Then if you're targeting a x64 process, then build for x64.  If you're targeting x86, build your app in x86 and it will always work.

Here is the function I recommend which incorporates this

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem is that you are using the wrong type which is why you need to cast it to a `DWORD` (4 bytes) The correct type (`BYTE*`) is often 8 bytes. With the correct type, you can drop the casting:

```
BYTE* GetModuleBaseAddress(TCHAR* lpszModuleName, DWORD pID) {
    BYTE* dwModuleBaseAddress = nullptr;
    ...
            dwModuleBaseAddress = ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
```

Another bug is in the call to `ReadProcessMemory`. You need the correct types there too:

```
BYTE* moduleAddress = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(moduleName), pid);
BYTE* b_moduleAddress;
ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, moduleAddress, &b_moduleAddress, sizeof(b_moduleAddress), NULL);
```

You should also add error checking to all your WinAPI calls to find out exactly where something fails just in case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198800/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-getmodulebaseaddress-function-not-working-p).